# Visual Studio Code - How can I disable option "Copy with syntax highlighting"?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

How can I disable [this new feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_copy-with-syntax-highlighting) in Visual Studio Code?

I am trying to use

```
    "editor.action.clipboardCopyWithSyntaxHighlightingAction":false,
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: There's already a feature request for that:https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21820

Comment: depending on the target you can still paste without formating...